# forward declaration of a class having static member

Tags: c++, static-members, forward-declaration

Am I doing anything wrong in below code. I am getting the following compilation error :

> **ERROR:** Invalid use of incomplete type `classSample`

But I have already forward declared the `class Sample`.

```
class Sample;

int Sample::objCount = 0;

class Sample
{
public:
    static int objCount;
    Sample()
    {
        Sample::objCount++;
        std::cout<< "creating object = "<<Sample::objCount<<std::endl;
    }
    ~Sample()
    {
        Sample::objCount--;
        std::cout<< "destroying object = "<<Sample::objCount<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Sample obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but i have already forward declared Sample class" forward declaration does not make a class complete. What is unclear in the error message?

Comment: move "int Sample::objCount = 0;" after the class. you cannot intialiase an incomplete type.

Comment: The compiler needs to see a definition of the class (not just a forward declaration) before it sees a definition of a static member of that class.   The error message about an "incomplete type" is your compiler's way of complaining about only having seen a forward declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward-declaring a class is a promise to the compiler to provide a definition at some later point. In return the compiler lets you use your forward-declared class in other declarations, where the content of the class is not required, such as declaring a pointer or a reference.

Defining members of a class relies on the knowledge of the content of the class. Therefore, a simple forward declaration is no longer sufficient: your class must be defined in order for the compiler to deal with its member definitions properly.

In your example forward declaration is not required. You should move class definition into a header file, include it in your `main` file, and move `Sample::objCount` either into the `main` file, or into a separate `sample.cpp` file.